# How does changing an image src when the user clicks on it work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple code where if the user clicks on the gif, it'll switch to another gif repeatedly until it reaches the end of the loop, where the loop restarts. This is the relevant chunk of code:

```
var storedColoredGif = document.getElementById("coloredGif"); //we grab the gif and store it in storedColoredGif
var onGifClick = function(){
    if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src === "/images/green.gif"){
        document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/blue.gif";

    } else if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src == "/images/blue.gif"){
        document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/yellow.gif";

    } else if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src == "/images/yellow.gif"){
        document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/red.gif";

    } else if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src == "/images/red.gif"){
        document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/green.gif";
    }}
storedColoredGif.addEventListener("click", onGifClick);
```

It's very straightfoward. All of the path names are correct and the gifs source is initially green. The program stores the gif in a variable, then in the function it checks for what the source of the gif is and changes it accordingly when the user clicks on the gif. But nothing happens when I click on it. Am I doing something wrong in my loops? If I had to guess, the problem is that I am correctly changing the source, its just that im never updating the html (but refreshing the page would set the gif to green again because thats what i set in the main html body). What am I doing wrong?

This is how the gif is put in the html (the green.gif is shown fine, its just that its not switching between the gifs when clicked)

```
    <img src="/images/green.gif" id="coloredGif" title="Click me!">
```

FINAL EDIT: thanks to 2 very helpful users below I was able to figure out that getting the src of the gif actually returns the full domain path, and as such my if statements never progress because theyre always false. Both of their solutions worked.

The solution was to simply work around the fact that checking the src returned the full domain path, instead of just the folders and gif path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.src` will returns a full string of the path: `http://example.com/img/...` instead of just what you're comparing in your `if statement`.

Here is a `console.log` of both `.src` and `.getAttribute` output for you to understand:

```
http://localhost:5501/images/green.gif // Output of .src
/images/green.gif // Output of getAttribute
```

It should be clearer now about why your `if statement` wasn't working: you were checking for something that was simply `false` in all cases. Do not hesitate to `console.log` values that you're checking when you run into those problems, it, in most of the case, will clear the situation.

Instead, my advice is to uses the `.setAttribute` to set it, and `.getAttribute` to get it, which returns the correct path that you're searching for.

Also, you may consider using `let & const` rather than `var`.
Here is the code using both methods as stated above.

```
const storedColoredGif = document.getElementById("coloredGif"); //we grab the gif and store it in storedColoredGif

storedColoredGif.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const currentColoredGif = document.getElementById("coloredGif").getAttribute("src")
    if (currentColoredGif == "/images/green.gif") {
        storedColoredGif.setAttribute("src", "/images/blue.gif")
    } else if (currentColoredGif == "/images/blue.gif") {
        storedColoredGif.setAttribute("src", "/images/yellow.gif")
    } else if (currentColoredGif == "/images/yellow.gif") {
        storedColoredGif.setAttribute("src", "/images/red.gif")
    } else if (currentColoredGif == "/images/red.gif") {
        storedColoredGif.setAttribute("src", "/images/green.gif")
    }
})
```

Comment: I've added the output of console.log for both method for you to understand better the difference and why it would makes your if statement returns false.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very new at Javascript. Is using let and const superior to using var for everything? Im very new at this so I dont know if its more efficient to use your method than mine

Comment: Use let when you know that the value of a variable will change. Use const for every other variable. You should use them over var everytime, they will make your code stricter and so, less likely to be flawed. If you are new, read that article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/, it will definitely help you. You are not forced to understand every line of it for now, you'll learn with the time, just stick to: if I change it later in my code, it should be a let, else a const.

Answer (score 1):

> img `src` includes the domain as well, for simplicity just check `includes`, which executes if the string is included in the `src`

[How includes method works - MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/includes)

```js
var storedColoredGif = document.getElementById("coloredGif"); //we grab the gif and store it in storedColoredGif
var onGifClick = function() {

  if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src.includes("/images/green.gif")) {
    document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/blue.gif";

  } else if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src.includes("/images/blue.gif")) {
    document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/yellow.gif";

  } else if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src.includes("/images/yellow.gif")) {
    document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/red.gif";

  } else if (document.getElementById("coloredGif").src.includes("/images/red.gif")) {
    document.getElementById("coloredGif").src = "/images/green.gif";
  }
}
storedColoredGif.addEventListener("click", onGifClick);
```

```html
<img src="/images/green.gif" id="coloredGif" title="Click me!">
```